# MVC parameter from JQuery null

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery

I am trying to implement sorting on a custom grid I am working on and having an issue with jQuery to MVC parameter binding.

I have a Jquery request like the one shown below

```
// Javascript

var dataobj =
            {
                test: 3,
                sortInfo: self.sortInfo,
                pagingInfo: {
                    TotalItems: 34, //headercontainer.attr("data-pagingInfo-TotalItems"),
                    ItemsPerPage: headercontainer.attr("data-pagingInfo-ItemsPerPage"),
                    CurrentPage: headercontainer.attr("data-pagingInfo-CurrentPage")
                }
            };

 $.ajax({
            url: self.viewModel.GenericGridHeaderModel.SortingCallbackUrl,
            type: 'POST',
            data: dataobj,
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (html) {...}
         });

// C#
public PartialViewResult GenericGridSort(int test, SortInfo sortInfo, PagingInfo pagingInfo){
...
}
```

At the moment I have non null values in sortInfo object in Javascript and I see that the values are posted correctly however inside the action method the values are not getting bound correctly. All I see is default values for the sortInfo and pagingInfo parameters. In fact the test parameter is getting the value 3 correctly.

For clarity here is my sortInfo model

```
public enum SortDirection
{
    None = 0,
    Ascending = 1,
    Descending = 2
}

public class SortInfo
{
    public int FieldIndex { get; set; }
    public string FeildName { get; set; }
    public SortDirection SortDirection { get; set; }
}
```

Can anyone tell me what am I missing here ?

Thanks all !

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think the properties on pagingInfo should start with a lowercase letter on your JavaScript object.  Can you make that change and see what happens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that you are not encoding the JSON payload.

You should be using either:

```
data: $.toJSON(dataobj),
```

or

```
data: JSON.stringify(dataobj),
```

Also, for contentType use:

```
contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
```

Here is more information on [POSTing JSON payload to MVC](http://haacked.com/archive/2010/04/15/sending-json-to-an-asp-net-mvc-action-method-argument.aspx)

Also, in the dataType option you specify the type of the return value, in your case, it looks like the action method will be returning HTML, but you are specifying JSON.

Answer (score 0):

Wow, as soon as I know that will not work. When you attempt to pass inner objects in your ajax data you must reference the inner objects properties strictly in the root of data ("innerobject.property": value)

Example:

```
var dataobj =
        {
            test: 3,
            "sortInfo.property1": self.sortInfo.property1,
            /* other properties */

            "pagingInfo.TotalItems": 34, 
            //headercontainer.attr("data-pagingInfo-TotalItems"),
            "pagingInfo.ItemsPerPage": headercontainer.attr("data-pagingInfo-ItemsPerPage"),
            "pagingInfo.CurrentPage": headercontainer.attr("data-pagingInfo-CurrentPage")

        };
```

Comment: I assume this will work as well since on reading more on binding I find that the search will happen inside the request object on the lines of <property>.<innerproperty>. But I think the second approach is easier to implement.